# How do you make the computer select random elements from an array?

Tags: java, arrays

I tried looking at other similar topics about this issue, but none of them solved my issue. I have basically made an array, that consists of animal names, and I am trying to tell the computer to select a random animal name, but I don't know how to do that.

I've already tried to use math.random, but it always sends back a random index value which is just a number. I don't want it to send a random number, but a random string.

```
 String[] animalNames = {"Raven","Chameleon","Lion","Cheetah"};
```

So, I want to learn code that can allow the computer to randomely select an animal name. I expect it to input the animal name which is the element but not the index, which is just a number.

Comment: use the random index value as an index to access the array

Comment: Get a [random integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/363681/how-do-i-generate-random-integers-within-a-specific-range-in-java) in the range zero to animalNames.length-1, then read the value of the array at that index.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand what you are trying to say, you see I just started doing a grade 11 computer science course as a grade 10, so I don't know much.

Comment: Hint: an array **maps** a number to a value. So, when you want to have a random value from an array, the only thing you need is a random number. A random **index**. Beyond that, there is also Collections.shuffle(). You can create a list of values, shuffle it, and simply return the first element. That works without the need to generate random numbers...

Answer (score 0):

You should generate a pseudo random int between `0` and `array.length - 1` then return the value with that index n your array. You can use [`Random.nextInt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt-int-) for that:

> Returns a pseudorandom, uniformly distributed int value between 0 (inclusive) and the specified value (exclusive), drawn from this random number generator's sequence.

Here is a full example:

```
String[] animalNames = {"Raven","Chameleon","Lion","Cheetah"};
Random random = new Random();
int randomIndex = random.nextInt(animalNames.length);
String randomAnimalName = animalNames[randomIndex];
System.out.println(randomAnimalName);
```

Comment: thank you, I will try that.

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
public String getRandomName (String [] animalNames){
Random rand = new Random(); 
int value = rand.nextInt(animalNames.length); // from 0 .. to animalNames.length - 1
return animalNames[value];
}
```